# Merge two collections by interleaving values

Tags: scala, collections

How can I merge two lists / `Seq`s so it takes 1 element from list 1, then 1 element from list 2, and so on, instead of just appending list 2 at the end of list 1?

E.g
`[1,2] + [3,4] = [1,3,2,4]`

and not `[1,2,3,4]`

Any ideas? Most `concat` methods I've looked at seem to do to the latter and not the former.

Comment: What if the lists are not the same size? What behavior do you expect?

Comment: @PedroCorreiaLuís Append the final elements of the longer list at the end

Comment: So solutions with zip or transpose can't do it, only jwvh or Mario Galic (updated solution) would satisfy your desired behavior

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So maybe your collections aren't always the same size. Using `zip` in that situation would create data loss.

```
def interleave[A](a :Seq[A], b :Seq[A]) :Seq[A] =
  if (a.isEmpty) b else if (b.isEmpty) a
  else a.head +: b.head +: interleave(a.tail, b.tail)

interleave(List(1, 2, 17, 27)
          ,Vector(3, 4))  //res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 3, 2, 4, 17, 27)
```

Comment: That is what I was thinking, you can´t use zip. Your solution is great

Answer (score 7):

Another way:

```
List(List(1,2), List(3,4)).transpose.flatten
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
List(1,2)
  .zip(List(3,4))
  .flatMap(v => List(v._1, v._2))
```

which outputs

```
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 2, 4)
```

Also consider the following implicit class

```
implicit class ListIntercalate[T](lhs: List[T]) {
  def intercalate(rhs: List[T]): List[T] = lhs match {
    case head :: tail => head :: (rhs.intercalate(tail))
    case _ => rhs
  }
}

List(1,2) intercalate List(3,4)
List(1,2,5,6,6,7,8,0) intercalate List(3,4)
```

which outputs

```
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 2, 4)
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
val l1 = List(1, 2)
val l2 = List(3, 4)
l1.zip(l2).flatMap { case (a, b) => List(a, b) }
```